# why am I getting nullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have the following code; however, it seems that I'm accessing an index in the arraylist that doesn't exist... here's the code. Any help appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<BankAccount> allAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

        Customer john = new Customer();
        john.firstName = "John";
        john.lastName = "Doe";

        BankAccount johnBa = new BankAccount();
        johnBa.accNumber = "111-222-333";
        johnBa.balance = 200;
        johnBa.myCustomer = john;

        Customer nick = new Customer();
        nick.firstName = "Nick";
        nick.lastName = "James";

        BankAccount nickBa = new BankAccount();
        nickBa.accNumber = "222-333-444";
        nickBa.balance = 100;

        allAccounts.add(johnBa);
        allAccounts.add(nickBa);

        ArrayList<Customer> allCust = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        allCust = extractCustomers(allAccounts);

        for(Customer c : allCust) {
            System.out.println(c.firstName+" "+c.lastName);
        }       


    }

    static ArrayList<Customer> extractCustomers(ArrayList<BankAccount> ba) {
        ArrayList<Customer> cu = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        for(BankAccount b: ba) {
            cu.add(b.myCustomer);
        }

        return cu;
    }

}


public class BankAccount {

    String accNumber;
    double balance; 

    Customer myCustomer;

}

public class Customer {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

}
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Where is the error occuring??

Comment: FullStackTrace would be helpful, if you can post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 BankAccount nickBa = new BankAccount();
        nickBa.accNumber = "222-333-444";
        nickBa.balance = 100;
```

No customer assigned here for second `BankAccount`.

But, you are trying to print customer details. For second `BankAccount` c would be `null`.  Any operation on `null` reference results in `NullPointerException`.

```
 for(Customer c : allCust) {
            System.out.println(c.firstName+" "+c.lastName);
        }
```

Make sure c is not `null` before making any calls on c to avoid `NullPointerException`.

```
  for(Customer c : allCust) {
           if(c != null){
            System.out.println(c.firstName+" "+c.lastName);
               }
        }
```

Comment: @BlueBullet: Took awhile to go through code, wasn't that easy.

Comment: @Nambari. You have Bull's Eye ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialisze your Customer obj in BankAccount class as below.

```
Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
```

Also its not recommended to access class variables like you're doing. Create get and set methods and access your Customer obj by invoking getCustomer()